# video editing: add mask has no menu

Tags: video-sequence-editor, masking

I'm trying to add a mask to my clip in the VSE but the menu stays empty.
Am I doing something wrong?

[image: ![Menu screenshot]

Comment: Did you create a mask in the movie clip editor first?

Answer (score 6):

The first thing that you have to do is create a mask.

There are two places where you can do this:

- In the *Image Editor*.

  [image]
- Or it can be created on the *Movie Clip Editor*

  Go to the *Motion Tracking Screen Layout* and load in your movie. Select *Mask* in the bottom options panel where it probably currently says *Tracking*.

  [image] --> [image]

Click [image] to add a new mask, or select the one you already made from the dropdown. Make sure your mask is named, so that you recognize it:

[image]

Key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> to add a new control point. Keep clicking to mask your object. When done, key <kbd>A</kbd> once or twice until everything is selected and key <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> last to connect the polygon. If you want the mask to move, key <kbd>I</kbd> to insert a keyframe, move the time cursor in the *Timeline*, move the control points, and key <kbd>I</kbd> again. They will glide in between.

When you are done with the mask, go back to the *Video Sequence Editor*, and your mask should be there.

[image]

Comment: @ideasman42 I didn't know that Image editor masks worked in the VSE. Thanks!

Comment: @cetagon Thanks for the edits! It always makes me happy if someone can improve upon one of my answers.

Comment: I prefer to create masks in the UV Image editor for the VSE. You can simply hit F12 which creates a render from the VSE this allows you to edit the mask on top of the output from your edit.